# How to estimate the distance between geodesics and points for Riemannian manifold with positive sectional curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Assume that $ M $ is a complete Riemannian manifold and there exists $ k>0 $ such that $ K(q)\geq k $ for any $ q\in M $, where $ K $ is the sectional curvature of $ M $. Let $ \gamma $ be a closed geodesic on $ M $. I want to show that for any $ p\in M $,
$$
d(p,\gamma)\leq\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{k}},
$$
where $ d(\cdot,\cdot) $ is the distance on $ M $.

I thought to apply the Rauch comparison theorem here, but am having difficulty characterizing the distance between the geodesic $ \gamma $ and an arbitrary point $ p $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can assume that $k=1$.
Let $f=\cos \circ \textrm{dist}_p$.
Note that $f''+f\geqslant 0$ (that is, for any unit speed geodesic $\gamma$ we have $(f\circ\gamma)''+f\circ \gamma\geqslant 0$).
In particular $f$ is convex in the complement of $\tfrac\pi2$-ball of $p$.
Hence $f\circ\gamma$ cannot have local maximum in the complement of $\tfrac\pi2$-ball of $p$.
In particular, the minimal distance from $p$ to $\gamma$ cannot exceed $\tfrac\pi2$.